# Sorting title with numbers in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, sorting

When I sort by title in Google Drive, I would like it to numerically go 1 → 2 → 3 … etc., but instead it goes 1 → 10 → 100 → 1000 → 1001 → 1002 … etc.

Is there any way to get it to do the first ordering? (Below is a screenshot of how it's ordered now.)

Note: I have `Japan2013a (2).JPG`, `Japan2013a (3).JPG` and so on also in the list.

[image: screenshot of how its ordered now]

Comment: The screenshot doesn’t show any abnormalities, as 1 < 10 < 1000 < 1001 < 1002 < 1003, so the sorting order is correct. Do you also have a picture named `Japan2013a (2).JPG`? And if yes, where is it?

Comment: If you want them to be ordered numerically, then add a leading zero: `0001`, `0100`.

Comment: @alex the japan2013a (2) is at the position 198>199>2>20>200. There are around 4000 photos so I do not know the exact position.

Comment: @jacob that would solve the problem but there are around 4000 photos, can you recommend a program to do that in bulk?

Comment: With Google Apps Script it is possible. This, would be more on topic for [SO] though.

Comment: See this ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#rename(String). With a regex or split function you can retrieve the ID and build up a new file name from the start, for all files.

Comment: @jacob sorry I don't do programming. what do I do this coding in?

Comment: Is there already a solution for this situation?? I know i could rename the files to 001, 002, etc...but I come from windows which "inteligentilly" sorts the files correctly. That, combined with the F2 function to rename a batch of files and 20 years of work and photos gives me aroung 50000 files to rename. Is google developing any kind of API to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It has been indicated on the [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/ozmaZq-YV7s) that if you were to put leading 0's as placeholders it will sort properly.

So in @Gavin Hudson's example if you created files with names starting:

01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11

It would sort properly.

In the general case, you need to find out the order of magnitude of how many files you have overall (is it 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc) - and use the number of zeros from that number at the start of the file-name.   So in the example, because there are less than 100 files, you need the zero's from "10", ie only 1.

This is fine for manageable numbers of photos - but it could be very tedious for larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive does organize your files/folders in a strange numerical way. For example, if you have 12 files it would appear as this:

1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

The only way around this, that I know, is to avoid using numbers to list things.

Comment: That's not "strange". That's just sorting by string, rather than number. The string "10" comes after the string "1" and before the string "2".

Answer (score -2):

One solution is (temporarily) converting the numbers into "currency", sort, and then convert again.